# Spider/Scraper in Python, insert data from multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, web-crawler

So I'm writing a small spider/scraper in Python that fetches and analyses different URLs using multiple processes.
My question is how should I insert the data gathered in the previous action?

Call a thread from each process? Add them to a global object and insert into the database afterwards? Other options?

Thank you.

Comment: look how scrapy do that https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is to dump the results from each thread to a .`csv` file in append mode. You can protect your file using a *context manager*. In this way, you won't lose any data in case your system stops execution due to whatever reason, because all results are saved in the moment when they are available.

I recommend to use the `with`-[statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), whose primary use is an exception-safe cleanup of the object used inside (in this case your .`csv`). In other words, `with` makes sure that files are closed, locks released, contexts restored etc.

```
with open("myfile.csv", "a") as reference:           # Drop to csv w/ context manager
     df.to_csv(reference, sep = ",", index = False)
# As soon as you are here, reference is closed
```

Answer (score 0):

My present bumble opinion is to use Pool, for a small spider Pool is enough.

Here is a example:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
pool = Pool(20)
pool.map(main, urls) # Encapsulate the original functions into the main function.And input urls.
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

[This the source code](http://github.com/TheoKm/Novel_spider/)

Ps.this is my first answer, I would be glad if was helpful.